# An example of Schur's lemma

Tags: representation-theory

Reading Linear representations of finite groups by Serre, I need an example of the following:

> *Schur's lemma:*
>
> Let $\rho^1\colon G  \rightarrow GL(V_1)$ and $\rho^2\colon G  \rightarrow GL(V_2)$ be two irreducible representations of a group $G$, and let $f$ be a linear mapping of $V_1$ into $V_2$ such that $\rho_s^2 \circ f = f \circ \rho_s^1$ for all $s \in G$. Then:
>
> *(i)* If $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ are not isomorphic, we have $f=0$
>
> *(ii)* If $V_1 = V_2$ and $\rho^1 = \rho^2$, $f$ is scalar multiple of the identity.

Can someone form a concrete example so I can see what's going on?

Comment: I've answered your questions before, and my sense is you are not ready for the answer. The map $f$ is a change of basis. Spend some time thinking about why the statement is true.

Comment: I'm also interested in this question, can someone provide answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you translate [Schur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) into the language of representations of finite groups, you get the following.

---

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $\mathsf{k}$ some field, and $\rho_i : G \to \operatorname{GL}\left(V_i\right)$ some irreducible
>   representations of $G$ over $\mathsf{k}$. Then
>
> 1) If $\rho_1$ is not equivalent to $\rho_2$, then there are no non-trivial $\mathsf{k}$-linear maps $T : V_1 \to V_2$ intertwining $\rho_1, \rho_2$.
>
> 2) If $\mathsf{k}$ is algebraically closed, and $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are equivalent, then every non-trivial $\mathsf{k}$-linear map $T : V_1 \to V_2$ intertwining $\rho_1, \rho_2$  is an isomorphism.

---

By a linear map $T : V_1 \to V_2$ intertwining $\rho_1, \rho_2$, what I mean is that $T\left( \rho_1(g) v \right) = \rho_2(g) T(v)$ for all $g \in G$, $v \in V$, and two representations $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are called equivalent if there is a linear isomorphism intertwining them.

---

Schur's lemma is a direct result of the following observation

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $\mathsf{k}$ some field, and $\rho_i : G \to \operatorname{GL}\left(V_i\right)$ some
>   representations of $G$ over $\mathsf{k}$, and suppose that $T : V_1 \to V_2$ is a $\mathsf{k}$-linear map intertwining $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$. Then
>
> 1) $(\rho_1, \operatorname{Ker}{T})$ is a subrepresentation of $(\rho_1, V_1)$.
>
> 2) $(\rho_2, \operatorname{Img}{T})$ is a subrepresentation of $(\rho_2, V_2)$.

---

Now, if $(\rho_i, V_i)$ are irreducible, and $T : V_1 \to V_2$ is a $\mathsf{k}$-linear map intertwining $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$, then $\ker{T}$ is either $\left\{0\right\}$, or $V_1$. In the first case, $T$ is injective, whilst in the second case $T$ is the trivial map. Now suppose we have the first case, then since $V_2$ is irreducible, we have $\operatorname{Img}T$ is either $\left\{0\right\}$ or $V_2$. So our options are

1. $V_1 = \left\{0\right\}$, in which case $T = 0$,
2. $V_1 \neq \left\{0\right\}$ and $T=0$,
3. $V_1 \neq \left\{0\right\}$ and $T \neq 0$, in which case $T$ is injective and surjective, and so $T$ is a isomorphism intertwining $V_1, V_2$

Now suppose that we are in the third case, and $V_1 = V_2$, and that $\mathsf{k}$ is algebraically closed, and suppose that $T : V_1 \to V_1$ is a non-trivial intertwining map. Then by the above $T$ is an isomorphism, and since $\mathsf{k}$ is algebraically closed, $T$ has an eigenvector $0 \neq v_1 \in V_1$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$ say. Then it is easy to see that the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$ is a non-zero subrepresentation of $V_1$, and since $V_1$ is irreducible we have that $V_1$ is the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$, and so $T(v) = \lambda v$ for every $v \in V_1$, and so $T = \lambda \operatorname{Id}_{V_1}$, and moreover $\lambda \neq 0$. It follows that every non-trivial intertwining map $T : V_1 \to V_1$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

---

Now, for a concrete example. Consider the representation of $S_3$ defined by
$$
\rho_V : S_3 \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^{3}) \ : \ \rho_V(\sigma)(ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3) = ae_{\sigma(1)} + be_{\sigma(2)} + ce_{\sigma(3)}.
$$

Then $\rho_V$ is not irreducible, because the two subspaces

$$
U = \left\{ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3 \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{C} : a + b + c = 0 \right\}, \\
W= \left\{a(e_1 + e_2 + ce_3) \mid  a \in \mathbb{C} \right\}
$$

are both subrepresentations. Moreover, it is clear to see that $U \cap W = \left\{ 0 \right\}$, and so for dimension reasons we have $V = \mathbb{C}^{3} =  U \oplus W$. Now, $W$ is one-dimensional and so must be irreducible, and take a moment to convince yourself that $U$ is irreducible too.

Now consider the representation $\rho_t : S_3 \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $\rho_t(\sigma) = t$ for every $\sigma$, where $t \neq 0$. Suppose that $T : \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to U$ is an intertwining map, and suppose $T(1) = ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3$. Then since $T$ intertwines, we have 
$$
t(ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3) = tT(1) = T(t) = T(\rho_t(\sigma)1) = \rho_V(\sigma)(T(1)) = \rho_V(\sigma)(ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3),  
$$

and so

$$
tae_1 + tbe_2 + tce_3 = ae_{\sigma(1)} + be_{\sigma(2)} + ce_{\sigma(3)},
$$

for every $\sigma \in S_3$. Taking $\sigma = \operatorname{Id}$ and $\sigma = (12)$ gives $ta = a = b$, and so $a = b$. Similarly you can show $a = c$ and $c=b$, but $a + b + c =0$, and so we get $a = b = c =0$. So every linear map intertwining $\rho_t$, and $\rho_V$ is zero, for whatever choice of $\rho_t$ we choose.

Now, suppose instead that $T: \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to W$ is an intertwining map, suppose that $T(1) = a(e_1 + e_2 + e_3)$. Then it is clear that $T(x) = xa(e_1 + e_2 + e_3)$, and so $T$ is a scalar multiple of the map $I : \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to W$ sending $1$ to $e_1 + e_2 + e_3$. This works regardless of the choice of $t$ (so long as $t \neq 0$ because $(\rho_t, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ and $(\rho_V, W)$ are equivalent representations.

Comment: For similar examples (in slightly different words, but only slightly), see also https://pure.au.dk/portal/files/120581284/intro_to_character_theory.pdf Example 4.3 and 4.4 (unfortunately, those are the old version of the notes as I don't have a good place to upload the newest version).

Comment: What you write as $\rho^1_s$, I write as $\rho_1(s)$. I have two examples. In the first case $\rho_1$ is the map $\rho_V : S_3 \to \operatorname{GL}(U)$ and $\rho_2$ is the map $\rho_t : S_3 \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. In the second case $\rho_2$ is the same, but now $\rho_1$ is the map $\rho_V : S_3 \to \operatorname{GL}(W)$

Comment: @john I’m not sure there is any substantial difference in our notations? What in particular do you take issue with?

Comment: rereading this, can you tell me what is $\mathbb{C}^\times$? is it the space of complex numbers excluding zero?

Comment: For a general ring $R$ with a multiplicative identity $1_R$ say, $R^{\times}$ denotes the multiplicative group of units of $R$. Where $r \in R$ is said to be a unit if there exists $s \in R$ with $rs = sr = 1_R$. In this case the ring is $\mathbb{C}$ and in $\mathbb{C}$ every non-zero element is a unit (because it is a field), and so indeed $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the complex numbers without zero, but when we write it we typically intend to emphasise that this a group. One last thing, the latex code for $\times$ is "\times".

Comment: and why is this a restriction $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "restriction there in $\mathbb{C}$"? If you mean why do I write $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ rather than just $\mathbb{C}$, it's for the following reason. A representation $(\rho, V)$ of a group $G$ is a vector space $V$ along with a group homomorphism $\rho : G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$. When $V$ is one dimensional, $V$ is isomorphic to its ground field $\mathsf{k}$ say, and then $\operatorname{GL}(\mathsf{k}) = \mathsf{k}^{\times}$. And so a complex one dimensional representation is a group homomorphism $\rho : G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$

Comment: ah yes, understood. thanks :)

Comment: I am writing up some material so may I use your example(s), but reworded to my taste if that's okay with you? :)

Comment: As a general rule, if you're writing material that is intended to be published in any form (by which I mean if anyone other than just yourself may end up using it), you should probably cite any material you use that is not of your own creation, even if you paraphrase it. But in this case, these examples are in some sense "trivial", and I am certainly not the first to use them. So feel free.

Comment: It's not publishable material. just causal notes. so are you a researcher/lecturer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96029/discussion-between-adam-higgins-and-john).